# How much minimum gravity required to form a black hole?

Tags: black-holes

A black hole has a high gravitational field and is formed due to its own strong gravity, which is defined by the Schwarzschild radius, $R = \frac {2GM}{c^2}$. However, it is not clear how much gravitational force is required to achieve this Schwarzschild radius. What would be the minimum required gravity for a black hole?

Comment: Wouldn't the gravitational field be something like:

$$ G\frac{M}{R^2} = G\frac{M}{ \left( \frac{2GM}{c^2} \right)^2} = \frac{c^4}{4GM}$$

?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That’s the Newtonian value at the black hole horizon. Note that this field can be arbitrarily small (since $M$ can be arbitrarily large).

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit

Comment: It's why I said *"something like"*.

Answer (score 0):

there is no specific minimum gravitational force required to create a black hole. But  I think that gravitational force also determines how much the object has to be compressed(if 2 object of same size has more gravitational force then we have to compress it a but not that much as compared to the object with higher gravitational force )

Theoretically every object can become a black hole  as long as that object has a size smaller than it's Schwarzschild radius for example: I heard that in a National Geographic or Discovery  documentry that to convert earth into a blackhole it has to be compressed to size of a tennis ball or something.

Here are the  [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) of different objects

Comment: “*I heard that in a National Geographic or Discovery documentry*” - This site is for expert answers to science related questions, not for sharing personal opinions or experiences.

Comment: @safesphere professionals cite their sources, no?

Comment: @JEB Yes, I’ve seen it in a documentary on YouTube.

Comment: @safesphere its not my personal opinion